# Isn't end-centered monoclinic same as monoclinic?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, crystals

monoclinic is simply an extruded parallelogram. If we place end centers on parallelogram faces then taking half of both diagonals and same height as before as 3 basis, its the same. That's what I think. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt at drawing the end centred monoclinic structure. The angles $a$ and $b$ are $90º$ and the angle $c$ is not. I've drawn two unit cells because the primitive cell spans two cells.

[image: End centred monoclinic]

The primitive cell is in green. Hopefully it should be obvious that the primitive cell is not monoclinic because both the angles $b'$ and $c'$ are not $90º$. That's why we use the compound cell, because it increases the symmetry of the lattice.